# Processing: Unexpected Token

Tags: java, processing

I've been double checking if I am missing any syntax, bracket...etc. and still cannot figure out why there is 'unexpected token i_'  at line 7. fyi- this is the second tab to define the class.

```
class Cell {
  int alive;
  int nearby;
  int i;
  int j;

  Cell(i_,j_) {
    alive = 0;
    nearby = 0;
    i = i_;
    j = j_;
  }


  void show() {
    if(alive==1) {
      fill(0);
      rect(i*scl,j*scl,scl,scl);
    }
    else {
      noFill();
      rect(i*scl,j*scl,scl,scl);
    }
  }
  void check() {
    nearby = 0;
    nearby+=Cells[(i+1)%rows][(j+1)%rows].alive;
    nearby+=Cells[(i+1)%rows][(j+rows-1)%rows].alive;
    nearby+=Cells[(i+1)%rows][j].alive;
    nearby+=Cells[(i+rows-1)%rows][(j+1)%rows].alive;
    nearby+=Cells[(i+rows-1)%rows][(j+rows-1)%rows].alive;
    nearby+=Cells[(i+rows-1)%rows][j].alive;
    nearby+=Cells[i][(j+1)%rows].alive;
    nearby+=Cells[i][(j+rows-1)%rows].alive;
  }
  void update() {
    if (alive == 0 && nearby == 3) alive = 1;
    else if (alive == 1 && (nearby > 3 || nearby < 2)) alive = 0; 
  }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing types in your constructor declaration. This,

```
Cell(i_,j_) {
```

should be

```
Cell(int i_, int j_) {
```